# Get \psbarcode to accept custom variable

Tags: pstricks, koma-script, pst-barcode

I'm trying to use `\psbarcode` in a manner that it will take a premade variable to render the barcode. MWE that fails is below,

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\newcommand*{\tozip}[1]{0123456789}

\begin{document}
   \begin{pspicture}\psbarcode{\tozip}{}{postnet}\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

If I replace `\tozip` with actual numbers it works... Anyone have an idea that will work with my `\newcommand`?

I guess my example was a bit *too* minimal... I'm actually using `scrlttr2` and KOMA variables. This MWE above works once the edits are made (thx!) but the actual example does not. Any ideas about this related example?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\newkomavar[to_zip]{tozip}
\setkomavar{tozip}[ToZip]{02115}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
   \begin{pspicture}
    \expandafter\psbarcode\expandafter{\usekomavar{tozip}}{}{postnet}
   \end{pspicture}
}

\opening{Dear Users,}
Than you in advance for helping fix this problem!
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Honestly, I reused that bit of code from something else. It compiled so I wasn't looking for it. :]

Answer (score 5):

`\usekomavar` is not expandable, so we write an own command:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}    
\newkomavar[to_zip]{tozip}
\setkomavar{tozip}[ToZip]{02115}
\makeatletter  \def\KOMAvar#1{\@nameuse{scr@#1@var}}  \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{%
   \pspicture(10,10)
   \psbarcode{\KOMAvar{tozip}}{}{postnet}
   \endpspicture}

\opening{Dear Users,}
Than you in advance for helping fix this problem!
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `\usekomavar` in an expansion context as needed by `\expandafter`.

For this task (but you can't use none of the advanced features of `\usekomavar`), you can do like this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\newcommand\psbarcodekomavar[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\psbarcode{\csname scr@#1@var\endcsname}}\x
}

\newkomavar[to_zip]{tozip}
\setkomavar{tozip}[ToZip]{02115}


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{%
 \begin{pspicture}
   \psbarcodekomavar{tozip}{}{postnet}
 \end{pspicture}
}

\opening{Dear Users,}
Than you in advance for helping fix this problem!
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```